# How to sign digital signature in pdf using python

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, sha256

I'm working on a e-sign project I've completed almost. But I don't know how do I sign digital signature coming from XML response, I've mentioned the XML response structure. I'm able to get data from certificate `<UserX509Certificate>` but now I'm not able to add signature inside pdf doc or sign inside it. Please help.

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

cert_str = '''
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFmzCCBIOgAwIBAgIDAYadMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMH4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAklO...==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----'''

cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(str.encode(cert_str), default_backend())
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EsignResp errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" resCode="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" status="1" ts="2019-05-02T15:15:13" txn="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
   <UserX509Certificate>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</UserX509Certificate>
   <Signatures>
      <DocSignature error="" id="1" sigHashAlgorithm="SHA256">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DocSignature>
   </Signatures>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
               <Modulus>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Modulus>
               <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
         </KeyValue>
         <X509Data>
            <X509SubjectName>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</X509SubjectName>
            <X509Certificate>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
</EsignResp>
```

Comment: Have a look at [XMLDSig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature) and regarding Python e.g. [xmldsig](https://github.com/AntagonistHQ/xmldsig).

Comment: Hello @Topaco I don't know how to do it can you please explain me a flow how it works so it will be easy for me.

Comment: Hello @Topaco doc. you've provide they are verifying signature but I've verified I wanted to add the verified signature inside pdf doc using python so final output will look like [this](https://www.pdfill.com/document_sign.html)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was primarily about XML signatures.

Comment: This post https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/sign-pdf-files-in-python describes how to add a digital signature to a PDF document using Python and PDFNetPython3 or PDFTron. However, PDFTron is not freeware, but maybe it's still interesting for you.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i need a java solution to do the same

Answer (score 1):

For a signature of PDF file, one would usually use a CMS in PDF signature, by adding a new PDF revision directly to the original PDF document. See the chapter "12.8 Digital Signatures" of [ISO 32000-1](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for more details.

If you want to sign a PDF using XMLDSig, the best way would be to use an enveloping signature format, by incorporating base64-endoded content of the PDF file to a ds:Object element within the signature, e.g.:

```
<ds:Signature ...>
    ...
    <ds:Object Id="o-id-1">77u/PD94bWwg...</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

And refer the signed element by its Id within a ds:Reference with applied base64-encoding transform:

```
<ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#Object" URI="#o-id-1">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>68ArneI9Ph...</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
```

For more information about de-referencing model please see [XMLDSig](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/) specification.